# Status questionis for whether a machine can or can't "think"

Tags: artificial-intelligence, turing-test

In his paper Computer Machinery and Intelligence, Turing addresses some arguments against the ability of a computer to pass the Turing test, such as the Theological Argument, the Mathematical Objection and the Argument from Consciousness. I wonder what is the current status of this debate; are there strong counterarguments for Turing's objections? Moreover, what is the most relevant bibliography on this topic?

Comment: There's tons written in the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_test.  Have you read that and the references there?  There's little point in us duplicating material already available on standard sources like that.  You might also be interested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_room, https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/1091, https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/15859, https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/15460.

Answer (score 1):

[EWD898](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD898.html) might be an intersting starting point.

> The Fathers of the field had been pretty confusing: John von Neumann speculated about computers and the human brain in analogies sufficiently wild to be worthy of a medieval thinker and Alan M. Turing thought about criteria to settle the question of whether Machines Can Think, a question of which we now know that it is about as relevant as the question of whether Submarines Can Swim.